# SQL Server: save temporary table on cache

Tags: sql-server

How I can save SQL Server temporary table on cache?

Any ideas?

Comment: not sure what you are asking, do you want to save the contents of a temporary table to a normal table?

Comment: What is a cache in this context? Something in in MS SQL Server?

Comment: Normaly the temporary table are alive for the sesion, I vont to keep alive not for the sesion but for a time

Comment: What will trigger the table to be removed from the cache?

Comment: The time, one culom is for the time of table creation. when read dhe tabel end the time is over te limit, one T-SQL refill the table with the new data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no feature in MSSQL that I know that supports what you want. You will need to handle it your self by saving to a normal table, but then you would need create your own unique session key and save in a table with the session key appeneded. But that can get messy. Can you store that data in a normal table instead?